# Reattach magsafe connector on logic board

Tags: magsafe

I accidentally removed the dc connector socket  while cleaning the logic board of my macbook. I can no longer put it back (it doesn't stay on or falls off immediately). Is it possible to reattach or do I need a replacement part?

Here's the part I need (It used to be soldered on)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given that you broke it off, then either send it for repair or get a replacement. You may damage something else while repairing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *may* be able to salvage the component; it is possible that you can continue to use it because it's not damaged.

If you can hold it down with tape (just for testing) and it powers up properly, chances are good you can resolder it back on to the logic board.  However, you can't do it with a typical soldering iron.  You will need a reflow gun that blows hot air so you can solder all contacts simultaneously.

If you don't have the skills to do this or have (or want to invest in) the proper equipment, your best bet is to send it in for repairs.